# After unexpected shut down, RabbitMQ can only start, if persistent data is deleted

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I'm using a single RabbitMQ instance (not a cluster), and all the queues declared are durable and all the messages sent are persistent.

I'm sending messages to RabbitMQ continuously, then (to simulate a crash) I kill the rabbitmq process and then start RabbitMQ service again.

The problem I face is that after the second unexpected shutdown, the RabbitMQ service fails to start normally.

Even though *rabbitmq-service.bat start* returns:

```
C:\Program Files\erl7.1\erts-7.1\bin\erlsrv: Service RabbitMQ started.
```

but the service is not running. *rabbitmqctl.bat status* outputs:

```
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@HCE-G971WY1': nodedown
```

Any suggestions, why the service fails to start?

If I delete all persistence data (\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db), then RabbitMQ starts normally, but then all my messages and queues are lost.

I'm using:

- Windows 7
- RabbitMQ 3.6.0 on Erlang 18.1

Here is the log file:

```
    =ERROR REPORT==== 18-Feb-2016::14:46:03 ===
    ** Generic server <0.154.0> terminating
    ** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',
                               {submit_async,
                                   #Fun<rabbit_queue_index.32.56515753>}}
    ** When Server state == undefined
    ** Reason for termination == 
    ** {{case_clause,{{true,<<189,10,73,71,182,201,144,167,110,15,200,171,200,160,
                              ...101>>},
                      no_del,no_ack}},
        [{rabbit_queue_index,action_to_entry,3,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,780}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,add_to_journal,3,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,757}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,add_to_journal,3,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,748}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,parse_journal_entries,2,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,895}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,869}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,scan_segments,3,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,692}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,queue_index_walker_reader,2,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,680}]},
         {rabbit_queue_index,'-queue_index_walker/1-fun-0-',2,
                             [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,661}]}]}

    =INFO REPORT==== 18-Feb-2016::14:46:03 ===
    Error description:
       {could_not_start,rabbit,
           {{badmatch,
                {error,
                    {{{{case_clause,
                           {{true,
                                <<189,10,73,71,182,201,144,167,110,15,200,171,200,
                                  ...101>>},
                            no_del,no_ack}},
                       [{rabbit_queue_index,action_to_entry,3,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,780}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,add_to_journal,3,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,757}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,add_to_journal,3,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,748}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,parse_journal_entries,2,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,895}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,869}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,scan_segments,3,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,692}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,queue_index_walker_reader,2,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,680}]},
                        {rabbit_queue_index,'-queue_index_walker/1-fun-0-',2,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,661}]}]},
                      {gen_server2,call,[<0.211.0>,out,infinity]}},
                     {child,undefined,msg_store_persistent,
                         {rabbit_msg_store,start_link,
                             [msg_store_persistent,
                              "c:/Users/212303924/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/rabbit@HCE-G971WY1-mnesia",
                              [],
                              {#Fun<rabbit_queue_index.2.56515753>,
                               {start,
                                   [{resource,<<"/">>,queue,
                                        <<"execution-processed-request">>},
                                    {resource,<<"/">>,queue,
                                        <<"execution-result">>},
                                    {resource,<<"/">>,queue,
                                        <<"job-result-queue-mirror">>}]}}]},
                         transient,4294967295,worker,
                         [rabbit_msg_store]}}}},
            [{rabbit_variable_queue,start_msg_store,2,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_variable_queue.erl"},{line,458}]},
             {rabbit_variable_queue,start,1,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_variable_queue.erl"},{line,440}]},
             {rabbit_priority_queue,start,1,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_priority_queue.erl"},{line,92}]},
             {rabbit_amqqueue,recover,0,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_amqqueue.erl"},{line,234}]},
             {rabbit,recover,0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,538}]},
             {rabbit_boot_steps,'-run_step/2-lc$^1/1-1-',1,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,49}]},
             {rabbit_boot_steps,run_step,2,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,49}]},
             {rabbit_boot_steps,'-run_boot_steps/1-lc$^0/1-0-',1,
                 [{file,"src/rabbit_boot_steps.erl"},{line,26}]}]}}
```

Comment: It depends on how the node is killed but there's always a window of time in which data on disk is out of sync. I think that right now there are no solutions on it. you could ask https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users or open an issue on github

Comment: I believe we saw this once or twice as well after rabbit us out of disk.  No good solution that we found other than to ensure that we didn't run out of disk.

Comment: Really hard to say... On the other hand don't use rabbitmq on windows and user a cluster. I mean why would you simulate a crash on a single node? What do you expect to gain, or what is the goal of this test?

Comment: To goal is to test guaranteed message delivery. And the test fails.
I have a system with to services, which communicate through a queue, but there is a requirement that none of the messages can be lost.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

A pivotal engineer answered the question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/f0akEFlQATU

The problem was that RabbitMQ failed to start after a force kill, because it failed to read queue index.

The solution was to change the RabbitMQ config.

Changing the value of the **rabbit.queue_index_max_journal_entries** from the default 65536 to 64 solved the issue. This config value controls how quickly queue index will be flushed to disk.

Note this might have an impact on throughput, but in my case safety and being able to start after a force kill was more important.